# Arduino nano -> 74HC595 -> LCD display

Tags: lcd, display

Greeting to all,
Newbie in the contraption above (Arduino nano -> 74HC595 -> LCD display); I would like some help from the experts.
I connect the 74HC595 to the LCD display using the 4 wires as described on the net.
I download one of the sample sketch and "voilà" the "World welcomed me".
But .... I would like to make use of Q0, Q1, Q2 and Q3 on the 595 for other functions like flashing an LED or connecting a 5V buzzer even if the lcd screen blink for a fraction of second.
ie.:

```
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print("Welcome to the world");

// flash the LED

delay(100);

lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
lcd.print("Welcome to the world");
```

Is it possible and (please) HOW?
Thank you for your support.
Eric

Comment: Could you post a schematic? It would make helping you much simpler.

Comment: The 74hc595 latches the output, so if the RS and E pins stay the same, the display will not blink. Please post a schematic and your sketch as well.